# Scala Compiler TypeRef to ClassDef

Tags: scala, compiler-construction

I am writing a plugin which watches for an @unmatchable annotation and throws a warning if it is found in pattern matching.

I have been able to find the TypeRef, but I can not convert it into a ClassDef so I can inspect the annoations.

I'm guessing that I need to get the root of the tree and use TreeOpts.find in order to get the actual ClassDef.  However, I can not find where the root tree is.

EDIT:  I need more than the root Compilation units in case a matchable annoation is included in a library.

Here is what I have so far.

```
class UnmatchablePlugin(val global: Global) extends Plugin {
  val name = "unmatchable-check-gen"
  val description = "marks a class unmatchable"
  val components = List[PluginComponent](UnmatchableComponent)

  private object UnmatchableComponent extends PluginComponent with Transform {
    val global: UnmatchablePlugin.this.global.type = UnmatchablePlugin.this.global
    val runsAfter = List("parser")
    // Using the Scala Compiler 2.8.x the runsAfter should be written as below
    // val runsAfter = List[String]("parser");
    val phaseName = UnmatchablePlugin.this.name

    def newTransformer(unit: global.CompilationUnit) = UnmatchableTransformer

    object UnmatchableTransformer extends global.Transformer {
      override def transform(tree: global.Tree) = {
        import global._

        tree match {
          case cd @ global.CaseDef(global.Bind(_, global.Typed(exp,tpt)) , _, _) => {

            //Need to turn tpt.tpe.sym into a ClassDef
            println("sym: " + tpt.tpe.sym)
            tree
            }
          case t => super.transform(t)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot turn types/symbols into trees because there might be a symbol that has no tree corresponding to it. It's a case for example when symbol is corresponding to class defined in binary class file.

However, as far as I understand what you are trying to do you don't need ClassDef. Symbols you obtained already has all information about annotations. Check hasAnnotation and getAnnotation methods defined in Symbols.scala (lines 1115-1118).